# Passing params to stored procedure located on another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure on **tempdb** database (under *System Databases*) on **server A**. The stored procedure has 3 parameters, **Param1**, **Param2**, and **Param3** which all accept varchars.

I would like to execute this stored procedure on **server B** for a database called **SomeDB**.

With the stored procedure, I'd like to pull data from different tables on **SomeDB**, and then put the results in a new table that will be created called **SomeNewTable**, which again will be located on **SomeDb**

Let's assume that the servers are linked.

How should I approach this?

Comment: The same was as on a non linked server? We need to see what you have tried and what you got stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the stored procedure on ServerB .   Test the stored proc so that it can run completely on ServerB when you are connected to server B.   So everything is happening in Server B.

Now just call the Server B stored proc from Server A.
On Server B  exec SomeDb.dbo.myStoredProc(p1,p2,p3)

On Server A  exec LinkedServerB.SomeDb.dbo.myStoredProc(p1,p2,p3)

Do not use tempDb for anything - you can not reliably put a stored proc in TempDb*

The fact that it will work in temp db for awhile is misleading.
If you are doing a coding exercise they may have you use tempDb but that is a special situation.

You will have to deal with the security jump from ServerA to ServerB depending on how the linked server was setup.

*(yes I know how to do it permanently - but I doubt it works in azure)